# Core Spotlight App Name does not appear in search

Tags: ios, corespotlight

I developed a music related iOS app (MyMusic) in Swift 3. Now when a user searches for "music" in the Spotlight, then I want to get my app "MyMusic" appear in the "APPLICATIONS" section of the "search results". I have been trying to implement Core Spotlight, but I have not found the correct solution for the issue.

When a user search on the Spotlight for "music" then in "APPLICATIONS" section of the search result, it gives back list  of music related apps (Music, YouTube, iTunes Store) installed on the device.

Similarly if user is searching "sports", then sports related app (Formula1) is shown in "APPLICATIONS" section of the search results.

How do I configure my app so that when user types "music" in Spotlight, "MyMusic" will also appear alongside other music related apps.

[Result for Music Related App Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLZQx.png)

Answer (score -1):

Those applications appear in the Music section because their **primary or secondary category is Music on the App Store.**

Before submitting your app, you must set up a category for your app in iTunes Connect. You can access this setting at **My Apps/{App Name}/App Information**.

[Learn more about App Store categorizing here.](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/static/category_definitions)